# Add a page outside of the current theme?

Tags: themes, theme-options

Is it possible to add a page that is totally blank and doesn't use any components of the site's theme? Or is the best way to do that to upload it separately to the web server outside of WordPress?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Why do you need to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When you say "*doesn't use any components of the site's theme*", do you mean "*does not load WordPress*"? Like place a `test.php` on the root of `http://yourdomain` and go to `http://yourdomain/test.php`? No, you can't pull it off. Not with the current technology. Sorry about that.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: We are trying to add a holiday card to our website, and we don't want our standard header/footer or menu or anything. We just want to start with a blank slate, and our designer will provide the HTML/CSS to use. I figured we could upload his files directly to our web server, but I was hoping I could keep it in WordPress and just change some settings for the page to not use the theme. Thanks!

Comment: @rryanp thanks for clarifying your question with that added context

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu "No, you can't pull it off. Not with the current technology." Why not? This is misleading...there's no reason someone couldn't upload a file to their own server and visit it.

Comment: @phatskat: May I remind you WPSE/SO is not a free coding service for people who have no idea about coding, but a place where a programmer could hone their coding skills? If one doesn't get that joke, they probably shouldn't be asking questions or searching answers here.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu this is also a place for learning and education. Sorry I missed the joke, it's kinda funny now that I get it's a joke.

Comment: "...but I was hoping I could keep it in WordPress..." -- sorry, why? If you do not need anything WordPress provides there is no need to load the codebase. Please explain ***why*** you need WordPress involved?

Comment: @s_ha_dum [see my comment below](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210304/add-a-page-outside-of-the-current-theme#comment390856_210306) - in my case I want to make use of customizations I've made to WordPress *as a CMS*, not as a web server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated with the added context from your comment.

You could do this with a custom Page template. In your theme, create a new file. In this example, my theme will be "mytheme2015," my new file is "template-holiday-card.php":

in wp-content/themes/mytheme2015/template-holiday-card.php

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Holiday Card
*/
```

Now, once you have that template file created with a header like that, you can use it in the WordPress admin when you create a new Page type. The commented out "Template Name:" part tells WordPress what to call the template in the backend.

[image]

Note: if you don't see the Page Attributes box, look in the Screen Options pulldown menu at the top of the page.

Now, you can put whatever code you want in template-holiday-card.php which (since it's blank) won't display **anything** by default.

If you want to allow your designer to input the HTML/CSS directly in WordPress through the admin, you could just have a call to `the_content()` in your template and allow them to edit the page's content in HTML mode. Your resulting template would look something like:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Holiday Card
*/

the_content();
```

Comment: This works and is a good solution **if the blank template needs access to WordPress functionality**. But if WP functions are not needed in the template, I don't see a point in adding it as a WP page at all.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu you should still have it as part of WP unless you really need the performance of not having WP's overhead. Keeping it in WP means that it won't get lost or forgotten about if it's just sitting out there on it's own.

Comment: I completely disagree. If you don't need WP functionality, you do not load WP just for the sake of having it in the same place. The use case you provided (allowing people to dynamically modify the contents of this template) actually means: "I need WP functionality = editing capabilities on the output". But if the template contains some added functionality that doesn't need WP at all, there is no point in running all requests to it through WP. What if it's a chat engine or a payment gateway handler?

Comment: That's what I meant by the need of not having WP's overhead: if it's something as complex as a chat engine or a payment gateway, absolutely do it outside of WP unless you have a good reason to try and integrate the two. If you're doing a simple page, as OP is, there's no real reason not to have it in WP. Either way is fine, but your original comment even says you can't pull that off.

Comment: @phatskat: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate all your insights. I added "the_content();" to my template file and tried to then add content to the blank page from the WordPress admin, but that didn't show up, but I think I'll be able to tinker with it and figure that out. Thanks again for your time. Thanks to you too, Andrei--we want it in WordPress for the reasons phatskat suggested...it keeps it all together, and we don't have to go to two places to make edits across our site. I do understand your points on doing it outside of WP though.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu What if you are more concerned about managing the content in the page than any performance overhead WordPress might add? Think about the case where you want a one-off page but you still need content editors to be able to modify the page, make use of custom buttons you've added to tinyMCE etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It really depends on what "*and doesn't use any components of the site's theme*" means. If I was required to come up with a solution to disable header or footer on certain pages, I would not make a new template, but modify the existing one(s), allowing users to set parameter(s) for individual pages/posts/custom posts using a meta box and than do checks in the existing template(s). This way they can have their desired content with or without footer/header. And use any exiting template.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Like I said, I want to use the WordPress page editor as the CMS, but I don't want this *one page* to have header, footer, overriding/inherited fonts, images, sizes, etc. So, basically, don't inherit *any* CSS or HTML at all and, preferably, don't have to go modify 1,500 theme PHP files to accomplish that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, if you do it via template, you will still load all the styles and scripts added by WP, active theme and active plugins, unless you unqueue them in `functions.php` based on template conditional. You can't do it in template, it's too late. I've done something similar for a client who required almost each page to be stand-alone, using a bare-bone theme and loading resources based on template conditional for each page, which used a specific template, designed for it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand but if the theme is bloated and you use templates, your templates will contain all bloat.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I don't know, this solution seemed to work fine for me. I have a blank page and none of the underlying theme content is loaded, at least according to JavaScript console, Elements, etc. This is what I was after. If there is underlying burden on the web server that an end user can't detect anyway, /shrug. As I mentioned already, being able to have users modify the HTML content using tinyMCE is more important to me than resource usage that may or may not even exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57067/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-aaron-bertrand).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, it looks like you got what you wanted and we're watching a classic american (movie). Let me know if I can assist with anything else. Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

After understanding your desired outcome, from the comments, here is my suggestion:

If you want to send a link to your customers with a nice card, you should probably use an image placed on your server (this way you are 100% the fonts are displayed exactly how the designer wants them, on every device) and link it directly. You could also place a stand-alone `.html` or `.php` file and link those directly, as well.

If, however, you want your existing content to be ornated for holidays, you should use a function in your `functions.php` to filter the result of header, menu and/or/maybe footer inside a simple date conditional, replacing the normal ones with the changed ones for the desired period of time.